# Cloned project with dynamic includes in composer.json

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have an application server, it is like a blog system (my wordpress killer). It is based in php hosted in github and using composer to manage dependencies. Each installation is hosted in my server (I make the installation for them). When a client requires a new "addon/plugin" I create a new package and host it in a private repository hosting. The problems comes when I need to add new package:

```
Client 1.
- package for calculate prices

Client 2.
- package for show a welcome message

Client 3.
- package for add a calendar
```

My application will have every package ready to be used in all instances because I am requiring them via composer:

```
"require": {
        "killer/calculate": "dev-master",
        "killer/message": "dev-master",
        "killer/calendar": "dev-master"
}
```

Now image if I have 2K clients and everyone of them are requesting custom packages. How can I provide an application (cloned massively) but just keeping in the each installation just the packages that each client need?

### Hypothetical solution

I was searching (if it is possible) for something like the following. For each installation, create a file manually where its content specifies the package to be required. For example, let's say each client's installation has something like this:

```
//composer.json
"require": {
}

//plugins.json  (this file is ignored via .gitignore)
{
    "killer/calculate": "dev-master"
}
```

Then, somehow tells to `composer.json` to require the data from `plugins.json`. By this way I am avoiding to create a huge `composer.json` sharing unnecessary packages for all clients.

Comment: why downvote? If I am missing something you can tell me and I could try to get the things better.

Comment: probably because you said "wordpress killer". Some people dont like people with ambitions...

Comment: I'd love to see something that will kill wordpress, but that excrement is cemented way, way deep sadly. Also, there's no way you can "include" stuff in composer.json. You can specify a post-install or post-update command which can execute something on the CLI, such as looping an array and issuing `composer require $stuff_from_your_array`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/4210) for allowing `composer.json` to extend another file. You should go comment on it to draw some attention to it.

The way you would use that feature is to create a `default.json` file that contains all your regular `composer.json` contents, including a `require` section that lists all the common packages you need.

```
// default.json
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0"
    }
}
```

Then have a `composer.json` file for each project that extends and/or overrides `default.json` like this:

```
// composer.json
{
    "require": {
        "killer/calculate": "dev-master"
    },
    "extends": "default.json"
}
```

The final result would be:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "killer/calculate": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

If you can't wait on the merge request, then you can go checkout the [composer fork](https://github.com/aripringle/composer/tree/config-extend) from the merge request's author and try it out.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Could be really cool if composer team merge that feature.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have created your own package ecosystem. So, you could work independently from Packagist and simply host all the packages yourself, probably using Satis.

The main suggestion i have is to introduce your application as a package into this ecosystem.

Your application `composer.json` contains only the packages relevant for the application itself.

```
{
  "name": "better/application",
  "require": {
     "another/library": "1.0.0",
     "another/framework": "1.2.3",
     "another/generator": "2.1.3"
  }, 
  "require-dev" : {
     "phpunit/phpunit" : "4.*",
  }
}
```

I think, that "cloning" the application for the customer/client is not a good idea, because it ignores that plugins have dependencies on a specific version of your application, which is not always "latest" or "dev-master". Let Composer pull the application by version for each client.

> By this way I am avoiding to create a huge `composer.json` sharing unnecessary packages for all clients.

- create one repository per new customer/client
- add the application itself and the packages requested by the client inside `composer.json`
- add a client config on top

For instance, the `composer.json` for Client1:

```
{
  "name": "better/application-for-client1",
  "require": {
     "better/application": "1.0.0",
     "better/app-calculate": "1.2.3"
  }
}
```

For instance, the `composer.json` for Client2:

```
{
  "name": "better/application-for-client2",
  "require": {
     "better/application": "1.0.1",
     "better/app-calculate": "1.2.4",
     "better/app-message": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Each customer might have its own setup, requiring different version of your application with different additional application packages/plugins (here indicated by using the prefix "app-").

In the end you have two essential files for a customer: a composer.json and a configuration file.

(How the application detects the available modules is another story. At least, the autoloading will work out of the box, when you register Composers Autoloader during the bootstrap of the application.)

---

(Sidenote: If your application is a multi-site application, then you might replace "cloning" by "symlinking". With multi-site, i mean an application which runs from one central place using a site id (often customer id). If you have the application folder with all packages for development in one monolithic folder, then build a relase folder by cleaning the development stuff out, so that you get a release version with a blank default config. Then symlink the application, the requested packages to the customer folder and place a configuration on top. This approach might save quite a bit disk space and doesn't involve Composer at all.)

Comment: `I think, that "cloning" the application for the customer/client is not a good idea`. At this moment, cloning is my unique choice so I need to work on it. However, your answer is very accurate for my situation right now.

Comment: I would also like pointing out a brand new Composer feature: "Repository Paths" https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path This is basically a split between application and packages folder for monolithic apps. In order to fetch packages you need application `composer.json` file, but in order to limit the number of packages, you could rename it and work with one `composer.json` per client inside the application folder: `composer-client1.json, etc..` each with limited set of require packages (and always reference the central package path).

Answer (score 2):

I would also encourage you to use the approach proposed by Jens A. Koch in his answer, having a composer.json file for each customer and requiring the main application and all required plugins. Composer supports this scenario quite well and I want to point you to the starting points:

#### Composer Types

Composer allows to specify [types](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type) for packages. You can define your own type to mark plugins for your application as such. Many open-source projects (e.g. Symfony with bundles) have adopted this approach for their plugin eco-system.

#### Custom Installers

You can register [custom installers](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md) that can execute for a specific `type` of composer package (i.e. the type you defined for your plugins). Then you can customize the installation process for your plugins, which means you can:

- move your custom plugins to specific locations,
- automatically adjust plugin configurations,
- and most importantly: provide a mechanism that allows the main application to see which plugins are available.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. require all packages ones..

It means one big `composer.json` for everything is running with your system / is compatible with your system. Maybe you will have to introduce a versioning system too.. So you could end up with `v1_composer.json` ..

But for each client load only the required packages. For example generate a `requires.php` for each client with necessary require statements which links to your shared libraries.. This will be the fastest solution and most efficient, because you sharing the code which you can share and you only load it when needed

#### Conclusion

Share as much code as possible... but don't use it when you don't need it.